# aws s3 boto retrieve objects by date

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

The format that I stored them in was:

> website/website/objecthash/xcord/ycord/likelyhood/year/month/datenumber/hour/minutes

Right now I have the bucket I want to pull them out of.

Say I want the most recent 10 stored objects. What is an efficient way to do this?

I have the bucket, what do I do with it?

My solution was something like this for get todays however I'm not sure about the logic for get most recent:

```
def getKeys():
    b = bucket.list()
    theKeys=[]
    for key in b:
        theKeys.append(key)
    return theKeys

def getDecompiledToday():
    time = datetime.datetime.now()    
    year =time.strftime("%Y")
    month = time.strftime("%m")
    day = time.strftime("%D")
    keys = getKeys()
    objects = []
    for k in keys:
        splitK= k.split("/")
        if splitK[6]==year and splitK[7]==month and splitK[8]==day:
            objets.append(bucket.get_key(k))
    return
```

Comment: I think this is basically the same question as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24282214/python-boto-for-aws-s3-how-to-get-sorted-and-limited-files-list-in-bucket/24290121#24290121

Comment: I believe that it is different in the sense that I stored the time/date already. I'm not looking for a native s3 method. Additionally I have the dates stored in a suffix fashion rather than prefix.

Comment: Edited my question to make it more obvious, Unless there's another solution that's easier my biggest issue is the logic behind correctly getting the most recent in an efficient manner. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that I came up with.

```
def getPastAmountDecompiledFromFile(number):
    if bucketKeys.__len__() > 0:
        Found=[]
        latest=bucketKeys[0]
        while Found.__len__() < number:
            laterFound = False
            for k in bucketKeys:
                if latest in Found:
                    latest=k
                current = k.split("/")
                best = k.split("/")
                if k not in Found and latest != k:
                    if int(current[6]) > int(best[6]):
                        laterFound=True
                    if int(current[6]) == int(best[6]) and int(current[7]) > int(best[7]):
                        laterFound=True
                    if int(current[6]) == int(best[6]) and int(current[7]) == int(best[7]) and int(current[8]) > int(best[8]):
                        laterFound=True
                    if int(current[6]) == int(best[6]) and int(current[7]) == int(best[7]) and int(current[8]) == int(best[8]) and int(current[9]) > int(best[9]):
                        laterFound=True
                    if laterFound:
                        latest = k
            if laterFound:
                Found.append(latest)
        return getKeyFromKeyNames(Found)
    else:
        getKeysInFile()
        getPastAmountDecompiledFromFile(number)
    return
```